# find a solution when apache2 starts

Tags: ubuntu

hi i'm working on a cloud solution, offering infrastructure for many machines. my problem is when i want to access to dashboard in the browser, apache2 caused many problems and won't start even when i make a force-reload 
here some screenshot of my terminal containing configuration file of apache,resolv,hosts and the browser message

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of this [search](http://serverfault.com/search?q=ah00072). There are already many answers to this question here on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

You already have another process that is bound to port 8080.

Sort out what process that is (hint: use `netstat`) and you'll be able to start apache properly.

Comment: when executing sudo netstat -tulpn| grep :80 it returns that tcps is already using ports 8080

Comment: Well that would be why apache can't use that port as well.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: Use a different port for apache or sort out whether or not you need tcps.

Comment: what's the right command for that ?